# Which http method use to get JSON data from server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I need to get JSON object with my data from the server with ajax. What method I need to use? I understand that logical will be to use GET method, but I don't understand how I can check that user not type this address as url. I don't want that user can see page with JSON.

Comment: Were is your code?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is with typing it or looking at the value in the console. But your really only option would be to look at headers when returning the data from the server, but anyone can set headers so it is not that hard to crack.

Comment: `how I can check that user not type this address as url. I don't want that user can see page with JSON.`  Don't do that.  You cannot differentiate between a request from your code and a request from a user who has access to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate requests via tokens inside the header. Therefor no user will be able to access your JSON.